# Drupal modules to make a recruitment website like drupaljobs

Tags: drupal

I am very new to Drupal, but I have installed it on my CpanelX. 
I am trying to build something like this: http://drupaljobs.epiqo.com/

What modules can I use in the design of something like this, background images, etc.?

Comment: Please refine your question, to address these questions I have about it: (1) which Drupal release? (2) What are your actual requirements (= add details about which ***functionalities*** in that hyperlink you are looking for) (3) what are going to be your "users" (4) what is the "business logic" you want to implement (4) do you need any kind of reporting, charting, etc? (5) ... (6) ...

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. That will greatly improve your chances on good recommendations. The better you describe your needs, the better they can match. If people need to guess (checking "linked sites"), they rather skip your question.

Comment: Did you email and ask them? So long as you are not competing, I imagine that they would be happy to tell you.

Comment: Since you are new to Drupal, you might not be aware of our sister site https://drupal.stackexchange.com/  It might be that they could tell you there. I would expect it to be built with Drupal

Comment: @Mawg looks like you're NOT aware about the fact that questions like "Is there a module to do X?" are considered off topic on DA.SE (even though "There is a module for it" is often used in Drupal-land ...). If you don't believe me, try to post a question like that, I bet it will be closed in a few hours at max. BTW: are you familiar with my meta post to make this site a target for migration of such questions on DA.SE?

Comment: Are you sure about this? And can you link to your meta-post? (If you mean pthis](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2444/is-asking-for-drupal-modules-and-or-themes-on-topic) then the accepted answer from @Izzy says that askin gfor Drupla modules is OK )  I do know that requests for software libraries are definitely on-topic, and as a programmer of \*cough\* decades, I can't see any difference between a library coded in C and a Python module that I can `import` into my code. We may need to clarify this on meta,

Answer (score 1):

The link you have provided is build using [Recruiter](https://www.drupal.org/project/recruiter) module. You can have a look at it. Internally, of course, it would be using:

1. CCK
2. Views
3. Blocks
4. Webforms
5. Tokens
6. Search

Comment: "*would be using ...*": to do what exactly?

Comment: Drupal 7 out-of-box has views, blocks module. So no need to additionally download and install. Whereas Drupal 6 doesn't have them. So one needs to separately download and install them. Depending on what version of Drupal one uses, it will vary.

Answer (score 0):

For a similar solution without the full distribution, for developers who have worked some with Drupal, the recruiter_features module alone here: https://www.drupal.org/project/recruiter_features appears to have the features needed without the full distribution.

Just tested the recruiter_features module alone and seems to work fine after enabling and pulling down any required modules for what a site needs to have enabled.
[image: Recruiter Features module after install and enable features modules]